# Map inside map not changing the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Currently I am mapping through and array and then doing a second map to try to remove unwanted objects from the second array.

```
 const activities = self.periods.map(period => {
        
         period.activities.map(activity => {
            let showActivity = false
            if(activity.teacher_id === teacherId){
                showActivity = true
            }
            else if(activity.substitute){
               if(
                  activity.substitute.type === 'tutor' &&
                  activity.substitute.id == tutorId
               ){
                  showActivity = true
               }
               else if(
                  activity.substitute.type === 'teacher' &&
                  activity.substitute.id == teacherId
               ){
                  showActivity = true
               }
            }

           if(showActivity){
              return activity
           }
           else{
              return null
           }
         })
     return period
  })
```

Currently it just seems to return the periods array exactly as it is despite the fact that the if statement that returns null does get triggered.

Comment: Seems like you want to `.filter()` instead here. I'm not sure what a mapping operation gives you. Also `period.activities.map()` (or `period.activities.filter()`) will produce a new array, doesn't change `period.activities` in place.

Comment: You can probably simplify the whole thing to: https://jsfiddle.net/L9t3xq0f/1/

Comment: @adiga I'm not even sure the `period` object needs to be recreated. It's assigned to `activiries` so perhaps flatMap into filter is enough https://jsfiddle.net/3249mdbv/ (I hope I didn't mess up the brackets)

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns the same length of array as the original array. You should use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
const activities = []
self.periods.forEach(period => {
   ...
   if (...) {
      activities.push(period)
   }
})
```